# How to handle API gateway error handling on react-redux application?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, middleware, redux-thunk

**Background:** Usually we all get the data from API calls. But sometimes API doesn't return the data and throws errors like 404, 500 ....

How & where can we handle those errors to notify users that something goes wrong ?

Can we handle it in Reducers?
or
We need to introduce a middleware who will catch errors?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take at tour of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Have a look at [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) Also on how to [Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Without any other context, something simple like checking the status before dispatching actions and having reducers for success/failure might suffice for now. Have you tried something like this already?
```fetch('/some/resource').then(res => { if (res.status === 500) { dispatch({type: 500_ERROR) } else { dispatch({type:UPDATE_DATA, data}) } })```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the API in the middleware. If get error, dispatch error action.

```
next({
    type: 'ERROR_HANDLER',
    error
})
```

Comment: How to fetch it inside a middleware?